# Differential equation + initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am new to Differential Equations (first week!), and am stuck with the following question:

Let $~y(x)~$ be the solution of $(x+y^2)y'=y$. If $~y(0)=-2~$ then

$~a. ~~~~~y(3)=1~$

$~b. ~~~~~y(-3)=3~$

$~c. ~~~~~y(3)=-3~$

$~d. ~~~~~y(8)=2~$

$~e. ~~~~~y(0)=0~$

$~f.~$ all answers are wrong

$~g.~$ there is more than one correct answer

I have tried resolving this with the algorithm I was given in class, which leads me to $y(x)=Ce^{-y^2-x}$, and then C comes out as $\frac{-2}
{e^{-4}}$. However, this does not tally with any of the answers (except $~f~$, which I doubt is true). What am I not seeing? And why is my answer wrong, despite the fact that I went according to the algorithm?

Many thanks!

Comment: thanks,Moo! Any chance you could give me a hint how you got to that equation?

Comment: I have tried creating an exact equation, but in vain. My reasoning was: $(x+y^2) dy/dx=y$, thus $(x+y^2)dy=ydx$, and thus $1/3y^3=0$, which is clearly wrong. I am not sure where my reasoning is failing, though...

Comment: Thank you so much. Everything is clear, except for the way to derive the μ. We only had one example so far and it was a very obvious one, where μ'(x)=μ(x), so μ=e^x. That's why I am struggling with it. I hope I will get a more in-depth explanation in class or in the textbook! Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you! And I guess my initial approach (as stated in the question) was wrong because I raised e to the power of something that included both x and y, while y depends on x? (I did actually follow the algorithm given in class, but it is blatantly wrong)

Answer (score 2):

Given differential equation is $$(x+y^2)y'=y$$$$\implies x ~dy+y^2~dy=y~dx$$$$\implies x~dy-y~dx+y^2~dy=0$$$$\implies \frac{x~dy-y~dx}{y^2}+dy=0$$$$\implies -d\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)+dy=0$$
Integrating, $$-\frac{x}{y}+y=c\implies y^2-c~y-x=0$$
where $~c~$ is constant.

Given that $~y(0)=-2~$, so $~4+2c=0\implies c=-2~$

Hence $$y^2+2y-x=0\implies y=\frac{-2\pm\sqrt{4+4x}}{2}=-1\pm\sqrt{1+x}$$
Now since the initial condition is $~y(0)=-2~$, which is given by the part $$y=-1-\sqrt{1+x}$$so we neglect the other value of $~y~$.

Hence $~y(3)=-3~$; $~y(-3)=-1- i~\sqrt 2~$; $~y(8)=-4~$.

So only option $~(c)~$ is correct.

Comment: One should reduce trivial fractions, such as $y=-1\pm\sqrt{1+x}$. To get the IC, the solution branch is $y(x)=-1-\sqrt{1+x}$, so that $y(3)=-3$, the value $1$ is on the branch that does not pass through the initial point. I would argue that the solution does not exist for $x<-1$. $y(8)=-4$ is also not in the available answers, and $y(0)=0$ does directly contradict the IC. Only option (c) is correct.

Comment: Thanks @LutzL. I have changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'd still say that there is no value to be had in $x=-3$. There is a singular curve $0=x+y^2$ that bounds the domain of the ODE, and by the initial condition the domain is $0<x+y^2$. The solution reaches this boundary at $(x,y)=(-1,-1)$.

Comment: At $~z=-3~$, $~y(-3)~$ gives complex value. So from here we can say that $~y(x)~$ has no real value.